# Audio playback using Android's own player

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I would like to know how I can android's own player is activated at the time of pressing a button, I have tried but when I press the button the application is destroyed.

This is the location of my mp3 file (Internal Storage / Download / Audio.mp3)

alsoI have added this in the manifest:

```
<android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

My code

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
           button1.setOnClickListener {

        val audioDirPath = File(getFilesDir(), "Download")
        audioDirPath.mkdir()
        val file = File(audioDirPath, "audionline.mp3")
        val contentUri = getUriForFile(this, "com.example.fileprovider", file)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent)

    }
        }
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace from the crash to your question.

Comment: `Almacenamientointerno://` would not appear to be a valid `Uri` scheme. `Audio/mp3` definitely is not a valid MIME type (use `audio/mp3`, all lowercase). "This is the location of my mp3 file" -- your prose has `Audio.mp3` and your code has `audio.mp3`. Android filesystems are case-sensitive. [Add `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) to your project, configure it to serve files from `Download/` in external storage, and use `getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63053632/115145).

Comment: Hello friend, I have already made your recommendation, but I have a little problem with contentUri, it said that the variable 'contentUri' is never used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.